# Circle on Edge with bevel modifier

Tags: topology

How do I get this to work properly with bevel edge modifier after I extrude the circle upwards it "kinks" in that area. I tried to quad that area but it doesn't really want to work as I intend it. I didn't find any appropriate example in the "clean topology guides" floating around the internet I do normally consult.

[image]

Comment: do you have a picture of what this part of your object is supposed to look like? It would help...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Vjo.png) can inspire you.

Comment: create a supporting loop between the edge and the circle so it does not affect the edge if you want to put a bevel on the edge.